# View list of controls while working in c# code?

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2013, controls

As a new student trying to learn C# I'm wondering if this is possible and how to do this.

While I'm working in the C# code, I want to view a list of controls that I have made in my xaml code.
What I had found was in visual studio going to view->other windows->document outline.
This gives me a window with the controls (see Document viewer in xaml), but only when in the xaml code not in the C# code.

What I want is to have a list of my controls while in my C# code because now I switch to xaml to see what names I had given.

Here are some images to hopefully make my question a bit more clearer:
[Document viewer in xaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5957.png)
[Document viewer in C#](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2TOA.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the document outline is context sensitive to the focused window. Have you tried splitting your main screen to show the C# and the XAML at the same time? Having 2 screens would be handy here.

Comment: Might be irrelevant to this question: Document outline wont work because it's work is to show controls of currently opened file while you have switched to code file so it wont show you intended behavior.

Comment: @MikeEason I might give it a try, but because I'm just starting I thought it would have been easier to focus on one window at a time. Having the two windows open seemed a bit difficult.

Answer (score 0):

The way the Document Outline works presently is that it shows the controls for the currently selected document. For a C# (or other) code file, there's no XAML hierarchy to present so the empty document outline is by design. Unfortunately that means that there's no way to view the XAML hierarchy in the document outline while also editing the code-behind file for that XAML file.

One workaround if you have multiple monitors is to undock the document outline window and the XAML designer and place them on one monitor. Now you can use one monitor to edit your C# code, and you can click onto the XAML designer whenever you want to see the document outline on the other monitor.

One other possible workaround is to leverage IntelliSense. You could name your controls with a consistent naming scheme, which would allow you to start typing a control's name and auto-complete based on the pattern you were typing. For example, you could prefix all of your controls with "Foo" so you always know to start typing Foo to filter to the list of items you want to work with. You can of course use more practical prefixes that might correspond to the control's purpose or area of the UI.

If you ever need to invoke IntelliSense but you cannot remember your naming scheme, you can hit Ctrl+Space and that should bring up the list of objects in scope.

Your idea is interesting however - it may be useful to see the document outline while editing the document's code behind. I'd recommend that you add this suggestion to UserVoice. You can add this suggestion to the XAML Tools UserVoice using the following link:

http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/category/44115-xaml-tools